# getting diagnostic information in CAPL

Tags: diagnostics, capl

i have difficulties reading any kind of diagnostic information with a CAPL test code.
sending a request is possible using qualifiers, but reacting on the response does not work.

here's a sample of the code:

i'm calling this function in the Main():

```
fDiag_read_faults()
{

  byte DTCasText[1000];
  char reasonOut[10];
  dword i; 
  diagRequest FaultMem_ReportDTCByStatusMask  diag_req;

  diagSetTarget("EPS218");  
  diagConnectChannel();
  diagSetCurrentSession(1); 

  diagSendRequest(diag_req);
```

et cetera ...
and then i would expect a reaction to the:

```
on diagResponse *
{
  byte data[4096];
  long size;


  diagResponse * resp; // declare response with no concrete interpretation
  size=this.GetPrimitiveSize(); // get length of response
  this.GetPrimitiveData(data, elcount(data)); // copy actual response into 
  data array 


}
```

but nothing ever happens.
the response comes on the bus, but the on diagresponse isn't executed.
i'm using CAN bus / UDS protocol.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a test module you should use

```
testWaitForDiagResponse
```

for waiting for the response.
You can then get the response parameters using

```
DiagGetRespParameter
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. actually you are right. i had to wait cca 2 secs for the answer to be available and the ondiagresponse to catch it.